# How can I change the look of a button

Tags: twitter-bootstrap

I have thisbutton here "withdraw" how can I make the name fit the button in 1 line?

Here is the code

```
    <div class="col-sm-4 pb-3">
      <!-- Card -->
<div class="card card-image h-90 " >

  <!-- Content -->
  <div class="text-white text-center d-flex align-items-center rgba-black-strong py-5 px-3 justify-content-center ">
    <div>
      <h5 class="pink-text"><i class="fas fa-chart-line"></i> Your Rewards</h5>
      <h3 class="card-title pt-2"><strong>Earned AGI</strong></h3>
        <p>AGI Dividends</p>
        <h3 id="myDividends">0</h3>
        <br>

      <div class="row">
      <div class="col-lg-6  pb-3">
        <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary  btn-block" id="reinvest" onclick="reinvest()" >REINVEST</button>

      </div>
      <div class="col-lg-6 ">
        <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary  btn-block" id="withdraw"  onclick="withdraw()">WITHDRAW</button>
      </div>
    </div>

    </div>
  </div>
```

here is the image

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try to add CSS white-space: nowrap to never wrap Or you could just decrease padding of that button.

```
.btn {
   white-space: nowrap;
   text-align: center;
}
```

or

```
 .btn {
   padding: 0;
   text-align: center;
}
```

Comment: great help , kind sir the white-space option worked